# What does it mean: $a\in X$ is open in $X \subset \mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm in a course of multivariable real analisys and I have to prove this:

> $a\in X$ is open in $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ (in the related topology  to $X$) if and only if   $a$ is a isolated point.

I don't understand what does  the first part means, after this I can do the proof, please unclear my doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a more accurate statement: "For each subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and each $a \in X$, the set $\{a\}$ is open (in the topology on $X$ related to $\mathbb{R}^n$) if and only if $a$ is an isolated point of $X$."

Comment: sorry, I don't know about topologic spaces yet, but till I know, $\{x\}$ is closed .

Comment: what means in the topology on $X$ related to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez He means the *relative topology* on $X$, i.e., where a set $A \subset X$ is open if and only if $A = X \cap U$, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

Comment: oh thank you, I got it!